# Associating data with GKSession

Tags: ios, client-server, gamekit

I am trying to make a server device that dumb terminal devices connect to. Since I want the server device to store all of the information about the dumb devices, I need to associate each peer with an object. I could do this by just creating a dictionary with the peerID as the key and the data object as the value, but I was wondering if there was a more standard approach, or if GameKit itself has some sort of implementation already available.